# References for Lie algebra extensions, Poincaré

Tags: reference-request, lie-algebras, general-relativity

I will be posting this to the physics stack since this is a physics paper, but I figured the mathematicians would be able to suggest more comprehensive references for me.

My future adviser just published a beautiful paper, https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.08304.pdf, and I am looking for some references/textbooks to look into the following concepts:

- Lie algebra (central) extensions
- Poincaré algebra
- Galilean algebra
- Maurer–Cartan forms

Thank you!
Cheers

Comment: Crossposted to https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/474018/2451